# Duplicating Kotlin mockito test code to Java

Tags: java, kotlin, mocking

Trying to duplicate kotlin Test code to Java. Consider the following class and test class of existing kotlin code.

```
open class ClassX(
        val a: ObjectA,
        val b: ObjectB,
        val c: ObjectC
) {
  fun someMethod() {
.....
  }
}
```

Here is one of the tests

```
class ClassXTest : ClassX(
        a = mock(),
        b = mock(),
        c = mock()
)
```

Trying to mimic the same code in java

```
public class ClassX {
private ObjectA a;
private ObjectB b;
private ObjectC c;

public ClassX(ObjectA a, ObjectB b, ObjectC c) {
 this.a = a;
 this.b = b;
 this.c = c;
}

public void someMethod() {
...
}

}
```

For the test class

```
public class ClassXTest extends ClassX{
 public ClassX(ObjectA a, ObjectB b, ObjectC c) {
    super(a,b,c);
 }
}
```

My question is how do I mimick in java the mock() that is set for the base class fields as below in kotlin.

```
class ClassXTest : ClassX(
        a = mock(),
        b = mock(),
        c = mock()
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Kotlin code defines a subclass ClassXTest which has a constructor taking no argument and calling the super constructor with 3 mocks.

So if you want the same in Java, you also need a constructor taking no argument and calling the super constructor with 3 mocks:

```
public class ClassXTest extends ClassX {
    public ClassXTest() {
        super(mock(ObjectA.class), mock(ObjectB.class), mock(ObjectC.class));
    }
}
```

I really wonder why you create a subclass, instead of just using the existing class and passing 3 mocks as arguments to its existing constructor, though.